# python - compare user input with list and append to a new list limitng the entry items

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, for-loop, compare

I'm learning the python with LPTHW and I'm trying to build own game as exercise 36. I want the user to enter a specific string from the set of 10 disciplines. I can compare the input with defined list, but I can't limit the user to only 5 items. Rather I can restrict the user to only five inputs but not to do both.

I created list of disciplines (originally strings-names

```
discipline_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Then I created an empty list

```
your_disciplines = []
```

Here's the code for comparing user input with discipline_list and appending user input to a new empty list (code from other answer).

```
while True:
    d = raw_input("enter your choice of discipline >> ")
    d = str(d)

    found_d = False
    for i in discipline_list:
        if d == i:
            found_d = True

    if found_d:
        your_disciplines.append(d)
    else:
        print("Incorrect entry")
```

I can use the for-loop for limiting the user entries, but I can't combine it with comparing. All of my attempts ran more than five times.

```
for d in range(0, 5):
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine both conditions, check the length of `your_disciplines` as the `while` loop condition and only exit when you have 5.

```
while len(your_disciplines) < 5:
    d = raw_input("enter your choice of discipline >> ")
    d = str(d)

    if d not in your_disciplines:
        your_disciplines.append(d)
    else:
        print("Incorrect entry")
```

Comment: Your code simlify it really well. I only had to make one simple change to check if the user entry is in the main list and add condition to check if the entry is not already in new user list (so user can't repeat correct inputs). It functions very well now, thanks

    `if d in discipline_list and not d in your_disciplines:`
          `your_disciplines.append(d)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `while` loop, you can try:

```
num = input("Enter your disciplines number >> ")  # This is not required if you want to fix num to 5
j = 0

while j < int(num):
    d = raw_input("enter your choice of discipline >> ")
    d = str(d)

    found_d = False
    for i in discipline_list:
        if d == i:
            found_d = True

    if found_d:
        your_disciplines.append(d)
    else:
        print("Incorrect entry")
    j += 1
```

**Some notes:**

Instead of:

```
for i in discipline_list:
    if d == i:
        found_d = True
```

You can do:

```
if d in discipline_list:
    found_d = True
```

Also, you do not need to use `found_d` variable.

A simplified code could be:

```
num = input("Enter your disciplines number >> ")
i = 0

while i < int(num):
    d = raw_input("enter your choice of discipline >> ")
    d = str(d)

    if d in discipline_list:
        your_disciplines.append(d)
    else:
        print("Incorrect entry")
    i += 1
```